# Solspace Freeform: cannot send email notification to multiple dynamic emails

Tags: solspace-freeform

I just want to confirm that, if I have a form with two email fields (email and email2) and am using the user_email_field.  An email can only be sent to one user (email).

I have a form with the following fields:

name1
email
name2
email2

If both names and emails are filled in, I would like both email addresses to receive confirmation emails.  I don't believe this is possible without using php.  Though I'm hoping I am wrong and that using Freeform parameters this is possible.
Any chance?

Thanks

Peter T

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs for recipients.

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#recipient_user_input